# Matplotlib set axes limits don't match shown limits due to sharex and equal aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written a little GUI that shows a tunnel section schematic and the induced settlement. The upper plot has its aspect ratio set to 'auto'. The lower plot has its aspect ratio set to 'equal' (because the tunnel is distorted otherwise). The plots have their x axis shared.

The issue I am running into is that the y axis of the lower plot does not show all the data. When I print out the y limits of the lower plot, the y limits are (-20,100) which should allow it to show all the data. The solution to this problem is to increase the x limits, but I can't figure out how to programmatically do this since the y limits output from the lower plot are not the viewable limits, which are about (-2,84).

Any ideas or fixes?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,sharex=True)

ax1.plot([-10,0,10,-10],[-1,1,-1,-1])
ax2.plot([-5,-5,5,5,-5],[-10,10,10,-10,-10])
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
print(ax2.get_ylim())
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to keep the x-axes shared, I believe you have to enlarge the bottom axes' height, or accept that the limits of the upper plot change as well when you change the limits for the bottom plot.

Comment: I am happy to have the x axis display more than the data limits if it prevents cutting off the data in the lower plot. The issue is I can't figure out how much to expand the x axis since I don't have a way of calculating how much the y axis is actually displaying. If I knew how much the y axis is actually displaying I could say xlimNew = (yLim/yViewable)*xLimOld.

Is there a way to determine the plot view limits rather than the plot data limits?

Comment: Did you try just setting `ax.set_ylim([min, max])` (and letting it change the x-axis as it needed to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This digs a bit down into the guts, but

```
w = ax.get_window_extent(None).width
h = ax.get_window_extent(None).height
```

should get you the on-screen (you might need to pass `ax.figure.canvas.renderer` instead of `None`) height and width.

You then know the ratio between `(xmax-xmin)/(ymax-ymin)` and can set your x-limits accordingly.

The fundamental problem here is that you have a set of inter-related numbers and you can only specify a sub-set of them.

Comment: Great, that is a nice workaround, code should be simple to convert from the pixels or whatever is output by get_window_extent to data units. Thanks!

Comment: it is output pixels.  There is probably a better way to do it, but this is the first thing that came to mind.